# Prove that there exists $c>0$ such that $X= \{ x \in [a,b];f(x)>c \}$ has measure different from zero

Tags: real-analysis

I'd like a hint to solve this problem:

"Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$  be a function such that $f(x)>0$, for all $x \in [a,b]$. Prove that there exists $c>0$ such that $X= \{ x \in [a,b];f(x)\ge c \}$ has measure different from zero"

I know that I must prove that , for all $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $c>0$ and an enumerable family of sets $I_1,...,I_n,...$ such that $X \subset \bigcup_{i\in \mathbb N} I_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |I_i|\ge \varepsilon$.

The problem is that the function is not assumed to be continuous, so I don't know if I address the problem firstly giving a $c$ and lastly finding the family of intervals or vice-versa.

Comment: The union of countably many sets of measure $0$ also has measure $0$.

Comment: Hellow, Daniel! I want to prove that $X$ has measure different from zero.

Comment: Yes. Suppose there weren't such a $c$ and get a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$A_n =\left\{ t\in [a,b] : f(t)>\frac{1}{n}\right\} .$$
We have that for every $n\in\mathbb{N} $ the inclusion $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ holds true moreover also we have the following equality: $$[a,b] =\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n ,$$
thus $$0<m([a,b]) =\lim_{n\to\infty} m(A_n )$$ and hence there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$m(A_{n_0} )>\frac{1}{2} m([a,b])>0.$$

Comment: Nice! Shouldn't $A_n$ be the set of all $t \in [a,b]$?

Comment: Yes, of course.